# Changing parent object , doesn't change prototype chain in other

Tags: javascript, prototype, chain

I have two objects foo and bar. Object.create built object bar setting the prototype of it to foo - ok.  When I update foo properties everything is ok, but when I change whole foo object for example to number, object bar does not change. As if the previous object foo was somewhere but I don't know where. I'm very curious about it.

```
var foo = { name: "foo" };
var bar = Object.create(foo);
foo = 2 //I change foo 
console.log(bar) 

//in Chrome console I see:
Object {}
__proto__: Object // __proto__ of bar shows to object 
   name: "foo"
  __proto__: Object
```

help. Maybe I miss something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `foo` is only reference to the object. When you set it as a prototype, it creates the second reference in the `bar` and refers to that same object. Then when you change the `foo` **variable**, which is only a reference to the object, to keep another variable like number, it removes the `foo` reference from the `object`. So you only have one reference which is in the `prototype` of the `bar` refering to the object.

`[]` is considered the value of the variable.

```
                        -----
  foo[obj address] ---> |obj|
                        -----
                          ^
                          |
                 bar.prototype[obj address]
```

After `foo = 2`

```
                        -----
   foo[2]               |obj|
                        -----
                          ^
                          |
                 bar.prototype[obj address]
```